# How to merge multiple excel files and skip empty workbooks

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I have to run hundreds of data checks every day and combine the results into a single spreadsheet so errors can be fixed. I'm attempting to write some python code that will do this automatically, but I also want to exclude any files that have no results. To make this a little more complicated, every excel file has headers, even if the associated SQL queries brings back no results.

This is what I have so far:

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
import xlwings as xw
SOURCE_DIR = [*filepath*]
excel_files = list(Path(SOURCE_DIR).glob('*.csv'))
combined_wb = xw.Book()
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', t)
for excel_file in excel_files:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    for sheet in wb.sheets:
            sheet.api.Copy(After=combined_wb.sheets[0].api)
    wb.close()
combined_wb.save([*filepath*]dailychecks_{timestamp}.xlsx")
if len(combined_wb.app.books) == 1:
    combined_wb.app.quit()
else:
    combined_wb.close()
```

This code combines everything in the given folder into one excel workbook, but I can't figure out how to skip or ignore the empty files. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to place multiple .csv files (by converting them to dataframes) in different sheets of a single Excel file. We'll be using [**`pandas.read_csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to create a the dataframes and a list comprehension to get rid of the empty ones (valid header with no rows).

```
import pandas as pd #pip install pandas
from pathlib import Path
from time import time

SOURCE_DIR = [*filepath*]
t = time.localtime()
timestamp = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', t)

list_of_df = []
for file in Path(SOURCE_DIR).glob('*.csv'):
    temp = pd.read_csv(file)
    list_of_df.append(temp)
            
list_of_df = [df for df in list_of_df if not df.empty] #to get rid of the empty csv/dataframe

with pd.ExcelWriter(f"{SOURCE_DIR}\\dailychecks_{timestamp}.xlsx") as writer:
    for n, df in enumerate(list_of_df):
        df.to_excel(excel_writer= writer, sheet_name= f'Sheet{n+1}', index=False)
```

The sheets will be named as shown in the image below :

[image]

You can change that by modifying the value of the argument passed to `sheet_name` of [**`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: Thank you! I added a few more tweaks for clarity and amended the sheet names, but this worked for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of checking if the sheet is empty:

```
for excel_file in excel_files:
    wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
    for sheet in wb.sheets:
        # if it is not the case that the last cell of the sheet is A1 and A1 is empty
        if not (sheet.range("A1").api.SpecialCells(11).Address == "$A$1") & (sheet.range("A1").value == None):
            sheet.api.Copy(After=combined_wb.sheets[0].api)
    wb.close()
combined_wb.save(f"{SOURCE_DIR}\\dailychecks_{timestamp}.xlsx")
```

The `if not` statement can be broken down into two parts:

1. Using the VBA "SpecialCells", is the last cell on the sheet [(which is number 11)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype) A1?  If it is, then either that cell is the only cell with data, or the sheet is empty.
2. Also, is the value of the cell A1 equal to `None` (i.e. is empty)?  If this is also the case then the sheet must be empty.

There isn't a specific xlwings function to check if the whole sheet is empty or not, as far as I am aware, so I had to use the `.api`.